# Cookie to remember the last visited top level navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

Read so much around the web now without getting any wiser on the topic.
Or a bit wiser on the cookie how-it-works - but really struggling with any jquery / js of this case.

Here's the case:
I have a site with tree target groups: clients, co-workers, vendors.
That is also the main navigation Clients | Co-workers | Vendors

There's fully fine that the three different target groups look at each others pages, but I would like a function triggering a top-banner(e.g. fixed, top:0); asking the user `"Would you like to visit the page for {based on where you where the last time you left off}".`

- The domain structure is domain.com/clients, domain.com/co-workers, etc...
- No logins to identify the users. (The reason i would like a "banner" just reminding that the user might be at the wrong place).
- Is it possible to activate an other banner/ modal/ message if no cookie is available, like: "Welcome new user. Are you a Vendor? - have a look at the... bla bla". 
  Just to make the user aware of the differences.
- The cookie it self...

  - long expiry,
  - able to be updated if the user next time "leave" on another level.. Possible?

Please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are pretty outdated tech if you ask me, you should look into [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (it has [full support](http://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage) for all browsers)

LocalStorage is just an object and everything you add to it will be stored for your domain so you could do

```
if (localStorage.userType) {
  switch (localStorage.userType) {
     case 'vendor': ... break;
     case 'client': ... break;
     case 'co-worker': ... break;
     default: // Invalid userType stored, probably best to just clear it:
       delete localStorage.userType;
  }
} else {
  localStorage.userType = prompt('What type of user are you? (client | vendor | co-worker)');
}
```

localStorage is stored indefinitely, even if you close/refresh the page, and it's shared between all pages under your domain and can store more data than a cookie

Comment: Ah sounds brilliant. Could you please explain more (i've read but still struggle a bit...). What is `switch case 'XuserType' : ... break;` ?? Please explain a little bit more. (If i paste this text i'll get an error on on the first case - why? how is this understanding the usertype and how do i launch the "banner")?

Comment: ah it's just a [javascript switch case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), the `...` doesn't mean anything, there is just placeholder. you should replace `...` with your actual logic for each case